# Why does mouse-wheel input steal focus to the window under the mouse cursor?

Tags: 20.04, xfce, ubuntu-studio

Ubuntu Studio 20.04, XFCE window manager.

This behavior has started somewhere in the last months.
As soon as the mouse cursor is outside the active window, scroll-wheel input will activate the window under the cursor and bring it to the top.

Before, scroll-events would go to the window under the cursor, but it would not steal focus from the active window. This is the desired behavior.
Now it steals focus.

This is the focus-mode setting, although it is for Gnome, maybe it does not apply:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-mode
'click'
```

This is the XFCE Window Manager Tweaks focus settings:

[image: The focus settings in "Window Manager Tweaks"]

Comment: I have the opposite problem, I want the wheel to bring the window to top and set focus to it, and it used to do that with xubuntu (xfce) 18.04, I installed xubuntu 20.04 and now the wheel brings the window to the top but the keyboard focus goes somewhere else, I have no idea where nor how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned: I don't know what other effects this option has.

Window Manager Tweaks > Accessibility > Uncheck "Raise windows when any mouse button is pressed"

Left and Right click do still bring windows to top and focus. Scrolling does not give focus, or move to top.

[image: Window Manager Tweaks]